# Freeze last frame of a video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video with a duration of 3 seconds. How to extend duration of the video to 10 seconds with ffmpeg: 3 seconds of original video + 7 seconds with the last frame of original video?

Comment: Related (as it can't be a duplicate if it isn't on superuser):
["How to hold the last frame when using ffmpeg" on video.SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/10833). Google is your friend and helper ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot. Just to post the solution (my video is without sound):

```
# ffmpeg -f lavfi \
         -i nullsrc=s=3840x2160:d=10:r=30 \
         -i input_video.mp4 \
         -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay[video]" \
         -map "[video]" \
         -shortest \
         output_video.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is much faster because it does not require re-encoding.

If there already is an existing audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -af apad -t 10 out.mp4
```

If there is NO existing audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -vcodec copy -af apad -t 10 out.mp4
```

- Note that the `-t 10` refers to the length in seconds of the final output, not the seconds to extend it by.
- The reason this works is because when the video and audio are different lengths, ffmpeg will extend the shorter stream to match the longer one by default (unless you use the `-shortest` option).

([credit Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197914/how-to-extend-a-video-by-freezing-the-last-frame-without-reencoding-the-whole-st/66202619#66202619))